# Refreshing Data Div inside Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to create a profile picture editor with a dropdown having two options:

1. Update your Profile Picture
2. If there is any profile picture it will show Delete options otherwise it will hide this options

template code:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <a class="dropdown-item"><input name="input_file" type="file" id="profile-pic-upload" style="display: none;" />
    <label for="profile-pic-upload">Upload Profile Picture</label>
  </a>

  {% if user_profile.profile_pic %}
    <a class="dropdown-item delete" href="javascript:" style="font-size : 14px;">Delete</a>
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    $('.loading').show();
    var url = "{% url 'user-profile-image-delete' %}";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $("#new_form").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+'{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}'+')');
            if (data['status'] == "success") {
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});


$("#profile-pic-upload").change(function () {
    var input_detail = this;
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: $("#profile-file-upload").data('action'),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data['status'] == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
                var randomId = new Date().getTime();
                $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.profile_pic + '?random=' + randomId + ')');
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But I am facing one issue: even if I click the **delete** option the dropdown is not refreshing and it still shows an option for deleting it. It only goes once I refresh the page.

Same way if there is no profile picture it only shows Upload Profile pic. If I update an image the dropdown will not shows the delete option. To see this I need to refresh the page.

How to avoid page reload to refresh dropdown contents?

Comment: You can try to initialize the false value to **user_profile.profile_pic** . once the image is deleted successfully. Like: {% with user_profile.profile_pic=false %}

Comment: how we can add this 


Inside ajax success???

Comment: It works in normal HTML as well as javascript try out.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem. You can easily solve this issue in your ajax call success.

What you need to do is just simple hide and show using jquery or javascript.

Lets say user already has a profile pic and the person clicks on delete option and ajax call is success then you should hide the delete option. (you can also remove it but later you will have to create it via javascript)

```js
$(".delete").click(function () {
    $('.loading').show();
    var url = "{% url 'user-profile-image-delete' %}";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $("#new_form").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+'{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}'+')');
            if (data['status'] == "success") {
            //$(".delete").hide(); // this will hide your delete option
            //Instead of hiding we are now removing the button then generating the button dynamically via javascript.
            $(".delete").remove();
            // But note one thing if we use class then it will hide/delete all elements with class of delete. so it's better to use id for unique elements.
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

For the other case where there is no profile pic and the user updates profile pic then you should create a dropdown menu and append it to the dropdown.

```js
$("#profile-pic-upload").change(function () {
    var input_detail = this;
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: $("#profile-file-upload").data('action'),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data['status'] == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
                $(".delete").remove();
                let dropdown_menu_item = '<a class="dropdown-item delete" href="javascript:" style="font-size : 14px;">Delete</a>'
                $('.dropdown-menu').append(dropdown_menu_item);
                var randomId = new Date().getTime();
                $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.profile_pic + '?random=' + randomId + ')');
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this should work but i think you should handle that show or hide dropdown using javascript by checking first if the profile pic is updated if there then show delete button else hide the delete button and when user updates profile pic then show delete button.

Comment: It's working 

I am new to javascript.....
How to append a drop down menu ..

Comment: The answer is now updated. I went with a different approach this time. Now we are deleting the delete option on profile pic delete and creating the option manually when profile pic gets updated.

Comment: This will get failed right , once there is already image and I am getting updated .....

Comment: Because it will append one more delete options

Comment: I have updated the answer to first remove delete option then append it again. So it won't get duplicated. But I believe now you have seen how it can work. So you can create a more thoughtful solution for this from start.

Comment: yeah this is not a good method .... I'm trying to refresh the dropdown in ajax success